# free desktop dbus error while installing any package using pip

Tags: pip, freedesktop

Whenever I try to install any package using pip, I get this error message at the beginning of the shell output.

> ERROR: Introspect error on :1.803:/modules/kwalletd5: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
> WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to open keyring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.803 was not provided by any .service files.

The installation of any package does not halt, but my curious mind wants to know what is going on here.

For clarification, my distribution is MX-Linux 21 KDE.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in pip. More recent versions might not show this behaviour. If you can, upgrade to the latest pip version. If not, you can use a workaround by setting the environment variable for the keyring:

```
PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```

You can set the variable everytime you call pip (inline) or put it in the environment. I prefer the first method as it keeps me testing, if the error is still existing, i.e. I do my pip actions like follows:

```
PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring python3 -m pip install tk
```

There is a GitHub issue about this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8090

Comment: work for me under osx, thanks!